# How to install GNOME Shell Extensions using Firefox Snap?

Tags: gnome-shell-extension, 21.10, extension

Firefox on Ubuntu 21.10 has migrated from .deb to Snap. Now, I cannot install GNOME Shell Extensions, such as [Night Theme Switcher](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2236/night-theme-switcher/), from the extensions store. Is there a good way to install GNOME Shell Extensions using Firefox Snap? Or am I stuck to building?

Comment: Currently there isn't. Use a different browser.

Comment: Use the apt version of firefox instead. `sudo snap remove firefox && sudo apt install firefox`

Comment: I guess the "Extensions" application in Gnome should do the updates.